# What SQL permissions are required to publish databases from Visual Studio Database Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, database-project

We have a SQL Server Database Project that contains our database objects. When a user who is a SQL SysAdmin tries to deploy the project it works fine. We want to setup another developer to deploy the database who is not a SysAdmin. They are part of the db_owner role.

When MSBuild generates the deployment script, it calls:

```
REVOKE CONNECT TO [SQLUser] CASCADE;
```

then at the end:

```
GRANT CONNECT TO [SQLUser]
AS [dbo];
```

It does this for every user on the database.

What access does the user need to not drop and recreate all of the `connect` permissions?

Comment: You might want to look at ignoring login/user objects in your publish options if that's a possibility.

Comment: @PeterSchott happy to do that if it's possible to do. Is there a guide somewhere?

Comment: This is the best I've seen so far for different logins per environment, but there's an option in the latest SSDT bits to ignore logins.  http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/05/ssdt-setting-different-permissions-per.html

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes across this, there is a way to ignore the connect permissions in Visual Studio 2017 publish profile.

Got to Advanced... -> Drop -> Do not drop permissions. This assumes that the "Drop objects in target but not in source" feature is checked.

However, this will also ignore revocation of other permissions, so be sure that this is something you want. This could still be desired in case the permissions are handled outside SSDT.